# Registering a controller at the config phase of the app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I am trying to use a same controller in two different apps. For that I need to register the controller at the config phase of both the apps. Right now, the code is like this:

FILE: myController.js

```
function myController() {
       . . . 
}
app.controller('myController', myController);
```

Now, as I want to use it in two different apps, I cannot register it in the `myController.js` file. How can I register it in the config phase of both the apps ?

One way I tried was by creating a provider that

```
function controllerRegister() {
    var self = this;

    self.$get = function () {
        return {
            app.controller('myController', myController);
        }
    };
}

module.provider('controllerRegister', controllerRegister);
```

Now, when I try to use this provider, it says myController function not found.

How can I make it work. Or is there a better solution to use same controller in 2 apps ?

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a separate module and require it in your apps.

```
app = angular.module('yourApp', ['sharedcontroller.appName']);


otherapp = angular.module('yourOtherApp', ['sharedcontroller.appName']);
```

More here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module